# Unit testing a PHP file with no method defined

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, methods

I have a PHP file that will only connect to DB and displays the resultset in an HTML table. How do we create a unit test script for such PHP file?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You don't. The recommended practice is to structure the code in a way that it is testable. You may want to learn more about "unit testing" or also "test-driven-development".

Answer (score 0):

If you did not defined any function on your code (and don't want to), this is not an ideal scenario. You can still write a PHPUnit test [starting PHP's built-in web server](https://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) and perform HTTP requests (using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)?). Then, ensure that what's being generated is consistent with the records of your database.

However, it may not be really needed to write tests only for this functionality, since it can be easily tested by hand and you risk to write a lot of duplicate code between your script and the test(s).

Comment: Thanks for your response swapgs. :) I would just like to know how do we test it by hand? Do you advise to just write some console logging for the variables that we want to check?

Comment: What do you want to test?